# Django-Oscar: Error extending base class "AbstractShippingAddress" from the app "address"

Tags: django, python-3.3, django-oscar

Hello I have a problem that makes me crazy. I want to add one field "company" to the class ShippingAddress. I do the next:

1. Forking the app order of django-oscar.
2. In the file models.py of the order app I write the next code:

   ```
   from oscar.apps.address.abstract_models import AbstractShippingAddress

   class ShippingAddress(AbstractShippingAddress):`

   from oscar.apps.order.models import *  # noqa*
   ```

I get the next error:

```
lib/python3.3/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 221, in register_model
(model_name, app_label, app_models[model_name], model))
RuntimeError: Conflicting 'shippingaddress' models in application 'order': <class 'oscar.apps.order.models.ShippingAddress'> and <class 'apps.order.models.ShippingAddress'>.
```

I'm using `Django==1.8.6, django-oscar==1.1.1 and python 3.3.`

If someone can help me I will be so grateful.

Comment: Make sure you are [including the oscar apps correctly](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/releases-1.1/topics/customisation.html#replace-oscar-s-app-with-your-own-in-installed-apps)

Comment: Hi Alasdair!! thank you very much, but I think I have all right. These are my apps included in settings.py: INSTALLED_APPS = DEFAULT_APPS + THIRDPARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS + get_core_apps(['apps.customer', 'apps.partner', 'apps.shipping', 'apps.basket', 'apps.checkout', 'apps.address', 'apps.order'])

Comment: That's my only suggestion I'm afraid. Hope you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well, your code looks fine but ...

Make sure you are using

```
from oscar.core.loading import get_model
ShippingAddress = get_model('order', 'ShippingAddress')
```

wherever you use `ShippingAddress` model.

If you have in your code a single line like the following:

```
from oscar.apps.order.models import ShippingAddress
```

You will run into this issue.